# Ruby array merge method

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm looking for a method that is equivalent to `Array#|`, and whose method name is in ordinary word.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [3, 4, 5]
a|b # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I'm not looking for new methods. I can write any sort of method that will accomplish this. That's not what I'm asking. I'm wondering if there's an alias. Is there a method like `a.merge(b)` that isn't a functioning method for arrays in 2.5.1?

It's described in the documentation for version 2.5.1 that `|` is the same as `Array.union(another_array)`. But it throws an error.

```
a.union(b) # >> undefined method `union' for [1, 2, 3]:Array (NoMethodError)
```

Is there such a written method for a `union`?

Comment: I tried `a | b` and simply works.

Comment: I'm using `2.5.1` as well

Comment: Yes, it works for me.  `a.union(b)` does not.  I'm looking for a __written__ method.

Comment: It seems to me `union` is just for sets

Comment: OK, `Set.union`.  The documentation seems to overlap these as inheritance is at play.

Comment: `a.|(b)`. Does this look **written** enough to you?

Comment: Not really.  I'm looking for a word like `.merge` but it seems there is none.

Comment: @Rich_F: out of curiosity, what do you expect to be able to do with a word that you can't with method `|`?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I'm just seeing if I missed it.  There's no difference in expectations.  Usually something like `|` is an alias for another fuller written method.  I thought I had missed it.

Comment: Ok. `a | b` is now written for you. May be `(a + b).uniq` more written?

Comment: No, this isn't about creating a new way around it.  I'm looking for the alias to `|`, which seems elusive, or non-existent.  Am I not finding it for some reason?  `a.|(b)` seems rather confusing in a language that is filled with aliases.

Comment: `union` was introduced in 2.6, it's not available in 2.5 and you're correct in that it appears there's no alternate named method for `|` (which is probably why they added `union`

Comment: @JayDorsey Thank you.  Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @JayDorsey, using `|` you can merge only 2 arrays, using `union` as much as you want. So they are no aliases

Comment: I don't see a method named `union` at https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html. Is there some other documentation you're looking at?

Comment: [Array#|](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-7C)

Comment: Cannot be reproduced. `Array#union` does not raise an undefined method error.

Comment: BTW, [`union`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Array.html#method-i-union) in Ruby 2.6 isn't just an alias for `|` – unlike the operator, it can take _multiple_ arguments. Just like `push` vs `<<`.

Comment: @Max Some people don't publish versions.  See how Jay Dorsey replied?  2.6 has `union`.  That's why I was confused.

Comment: @sawa What version are you running?  Please read the OP.  Version 2.5.1, not the version you're using.

Comment: @Rich_F It does say that you are asking for a method that does not function in Ruby 2.5.1. And `union` is not defined for arrays in Ruby 2.5.1. Doesn't that satisfy your requirement? Furthermore, that does not say anything about the version you have, which implies you want the method to work in the newest Ruby. Please read your own OP.

Comment: @Rich_F I can understand you were confused, since Ruby 2.6 has the method. You said the documentation for 2.5.1 mentioned `Array#union`, so I was trying to figure out where you were seeing that.

Comment: @Max People don't always mention the version they're talking about, and just went ahead saying the method `union` could be used, and I kept getting errors.

Answer (score 3):

`Array#union` works fine in Ruby 2.6, but if it's not in Ruby 2.5 and you insist on having a method named `union`, the following worked like a champ for me in Ruby 2.3.7:

```
[1,2,3].union [4,5,6]  # => NoMethodError: undefined method `union' for [1, 2, 3]:Array

class Array
  def union(other)
    self | other
  end
end

[1,2,3].union [4,5,6]  # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

To get functionality comparable to 2.6's `Array#union` documented behavior in earlier versions of Ruby:

```
class Array
  def union(*others)
    others.inject(self, &:|)
  end
end

[1,2].union [3,4], [5]  # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[10,11].union           # => [10, 11]
```

Comment: I've just tripped over the `.union` but that might have been for a `Set` only.  I'm not insisting, I'm just looking to see if I haven't found it.  I can always run off to a `Set`.

Comment: Then you need to rewrite the question.  You explicitly said "I'm looking for a written method."  Since one doesn't exist, it's easy to write one if that's your need.  If that's not your need, explain your need more unambiguously.

Comment: Yes, one that's already present.  I further explained how the documentation lead me to `.union`.  `Looking for`, not requesting to have one written for me, which I'm capable of doing, as evidence in my original post.

Comment: Ah, so you don't have a coding question.  You want others to confirm the absence of a particular implementation feature, which you could observe by direct testing.  In that case I don't see any point to your question.

Comment: I direct tested it.  I posted that direct test in my original post.  Documentation said otherwise.  Read the question as posted.

Comment: No, documentation does not say otherwise: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Array.html

Comment: Alternatively: `others.inject(self, &:|)` – more concise and doesn't alter the argument.

Comment: @pjs There is no `union` there.  I saw a reference to `array.union` and I stated the version I was using.  Version `2.6` does have `array.union`.  You still don't understand I was asking for clarification.  This isn't a puzzle, it's a question.  Documentation is a big part of software.

Comment: @Stefan Very elegant, I've modified my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

There's no exact equivalent for `Array#|`, even in Ruby 2.6.

[`Array#union`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Array.html#method-i-union) is implemented in [`array.c#rb_ary_union_multi`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_6_1/array.c#L6803) while [`Array#|`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Array.html#method-i-7C) is implemented in [`array.c#rb_ary_or`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_6_1/array.c#L6864).

They both use `rb_ary_union` under the hood for small arrays (less than 16 elements) and `rb_ary_union_hash` for larger arrays but `rb_ary_union_multi` accepts more than 2 arguments:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [3, 4, 5]
c = [4, 5, 6]

a.union(b, c)
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
a.|(b, c)
# ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1))
```